# Python data structure for dice roll emulator

Tags: python, list

So I made a dice rolling simulator in python, and while it does everything that I want it to I was told I could implement lists or a dictionary and it would be "better" code.  I have tried adding both to my code and am completely lost.  If any of you could help/show me that would be awesome. Here's my code, thanks so much.

```
from random import randint
print ""
die_amount = raw_input(">How many dice would you like to roll?: " )
die_amount = int(die_amount)
print ""
print "\t %s die are being rolled:" % die_amount

def dieroll(die_amount):
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    for i in range(1, die_amount+1):
        roll = randint(1,6)
        print "\t You rolled: %s" % roll

        if roll == 1:
                one +=1
        elif roll == 2:
                two +=1
        elif roll ==3:
                three +=1
        elif roll == 4:
                four +=1
        elif roll == 5:
                five+=1
        elif roll == 6:
                six +=1

    print """  
        One's rolled: %s
        Two's rolled: %s
        Three's rolled: %s
        Four's rolled: %s
        Five's rolled: %s
        Six's rolled: %s
        """ % (one, two, three, four, five, six )
    return [one, two, three, four, five, six]

dieroll(die_amount)
```

Comment: Regarding '"better" code' @rcline6: you may wan't to execute `python -c "import this"` from the shell to read _The Zen of Python._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`Counter` data structure](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does exactly what you are trying to do.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()

for i in range(die_amount):
    roll = randint(1,6)
    c[roll] += 1
```

Or, even easier:

```
c = Counter(randint(1,6) for i in range(die_amount))
```

`c[1]` then contains the number of times `1` was rolled etc.

To print out the roll counts, you can use

```
for number, count in c.iteritems():
    print "{}'s rolled: {}".format(number, count)
```

---

A `Counter` is basically a Python dictionary with a default value of zero. This makes it particularly suitable for counting how many objects occur in a list, for instance.

There are several reasons why this approach works better than keeping a separate variable for each count.

- If you wanted to have a hundred-sided dice, you would have to define 100 separate variables. That's much more error prone.
- It's, in principle, much faster. Having six different variables necessitates looping through them with a series of if-statements.  Imagine you roll a six. You will have to evaluate five different if-statements until you get to `if roll == 6`. By contrast, the counter uses a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), so `c[roll]` takes the same amount of time, regardless of how many rolls you make.

This begs the question: how can you know when you should be using a collection as opposed to a set of variables? The rule of thumb is that if a set of objects are different instances of the same thing, and we intend to use each object in exactly the same manner, they probably belong in a collection. In this case, a roll of 1 or a roll of 4 is essentially identical as far as the program flow is concerned. We will always treat them identically. They should therefore be kept in a collection.

Comment: Awesome! this sounds like it is exactly what I needed.  Now where would I put it in my code? Can I just add the second code to my for loop? how would I get it to print out? Thanks so much!

Comment: You probably want the import statement at the top. The body of your die_roll function should then just become `return Counter(randint(1,6) for i in range(die_amount))`. I suggest moving the print statements to a separate function (that way, you can re-use your die roll function in different programs without cluttering up your output).

Comment: I suggest you take some of the bits that I outlined and play with them in a Python shell to get an idea of how they fit together.

Comment: Okay you are awesome, I got it to work so at the end it would print it in this  format
({6:3, 3:1, 4:1}) like that if I rolled 5 dice, would I be able to print a counter in order like 1:0, 2:0 3:1 ect. or could I not? also could I add a string to it like in my code or no? But thank you, it was a huge help!

Comment: The print statement wrapped in a for-loop in my answer should print `1's rolled: 0` ... Is that not what you want -- you may want to read about Python's format statement (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format )? 

In general, you can iterate through elements in a dictionary (or a counter) with a for loop like `for key, value in c.iteritems(): #do something with key and value` . You should be able to modify this to print however you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer that more closely matches your original implementation, but uses a list instead, here is a replacement for `dieroll()`:

```
def dieroll(die_amount):
    rolls = [0] * 6
    for i in range(die_amount):
        roll = randint(1,6)
        print "\t You rolled: %s" % roll
        rolls[roll-1] += 1

    print """  
        One's rolled: %s
        Two's rolled: %s
        Three's rolled: %s
        Four's rolled: %s
        Five's rolled: %s
        Six's rolled: %s
        """ % tuple(rolls)
    return rolls
```

Comment: This is awesome! that allows me to still print my strings! Thanks for the help!